# How to use default values with Spray Json?

Tags: json, scala, spray-json

I'm using [Spray Json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json) and want to use the default values defined in case classes, if a value is missing in the Json that populates the objects.

**Example**

Let's say I want to create an object from the case class `Person` but using a json document without `age` to do so:

```
case class Person(name: String, city: String, age: Int = -1)

{"name": "john", "city": "Somecity"}
```

How can I use the default value with Spray Json?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740925/what-is-a-good-way-to-handle-default-values-with-spray-json

Comment: This refers to an [two year old pull request](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/pull/56), which in turn refers to [#93](https://github.com/spray/spray-json/pull/93) (status: open). It seems like spray json is sleeping :-(

Answer (score 4):

The only way I know how to do this is to use `Option[T]` as field type. And, if the field is optional, this is the semantically right way to do it:

```
case class Person(name: String, city: String, age: Option[Int])
```

When age is not present, age will be None. Since from your example, you use a absurd value (-1) as a marker that age is absent, using an `Option` will help you much more.

But, if you really need to have a default value, you can either have another `case class` that is filled from the one you've got from the JSON, using `getOrElse`, or use `getOrElse(defaultValue)` in your code when you need it.

Comment: The example has not much in common with my actual code where I wouldn't use -1 as a marker, but thanks for the hint anyway ;-)

Comment: I use a lot of JSON->Case Class. What we usually do is to create an intermediary case class that gets the values from JSON, then fill another final case class with the default values.

Comment: It would be nice if spray json recognized parameters with default values as optional as well and took the default value. In my case, `case class Person(name: String, city: String, age: Option[Int] = Some(25))` still leaves `age` as `None`.

Comment: Ideally, `case class Person(name: String, city: String, age:Int = 25)` should set `age` to `25`.